WM8731 correctly set doesn't detected in Embedded Linux
On a SoM imx6-based with wm8731 on board, I set it in device tree:
    sound {
        compatible = "fsl,imx-audio-wm8731";
        model = "wm8731-audio";
        cpu-dai = <&sai2>;
        audio-codec = <&codec>;
        audio-routing =
            "Headphone Jack",   "LHPOUT",
            "Headphone Jack",   "RHPOUT",
            "LLINEIN",      "Line Jack",
            "RLINEIN",      "Line Jack";
    };

&i2c2 {
    clock_frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c2>;
    status = "okay";

    codec: wm8731@1a {
        compatible = "wlf,wm8731"; /* codec audio */
        reg = <0x1a>;
        clocks = <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_SAI2>;
        clock-names = "mclk";
    }; /* fine codec: wm8731@1a */

I activate also in menuconfig, inside the appropriate audio section.
During the initial bootlog, this message appears:
wm8731 1-001a: Failed to issue reset: -5
wm8731 1-001a: ASoC: failed to probe component -5
imx-wm8731 sound: ASoC: failed to instantiate card -5
imx-wm8731 sound: snd_soc_register_card failed (-5)
imx-wm8731: probe of sound failed with error -5

So, I have two different SoM: one works with no problem, the other one shows the error mentioned. It seems to be a hardware problem, but if I place the wrong board on a different carrier board, it sounds perfectly.
Same, U-Boot, same SPL, same dtb file, same zImage.
I don't know how to proceed to inspect. Any suggestion?

This doesn't seem to be a software issue that can be solved with the information provided. Since the problem changes with different hardware, then it's not really a software issue. Does that I2C bus extend out to the carrier board? What is custom hardware? What is untested or incompletely tested hardware? Are you trying to use Linux to test your hardware?

SoM is  a DART-6-UL made by Variscite. I2C for audiocodec I think doesn't extend out from the SoM, because the SoM gives 2 I2C channels for external peripheral but not for its internal devices. I'm using Linux, but I don't know what kind of test coudl I performed since during initial boot my Kernel doesn't detect WM8731, thus I'm not how to do to continue.

The utility i2cdetect can be used to scan a bus.

i2cdetect seems to show correclty all devices connected, both interal to the SoM and external.

I checked the I2C using the oscilloscope: where no audio occurred only the audio peripheral address passed on the bus. Where audio is OKm after audio peripheral address also some data are sent to the WM8731. But if I placed the "wrong" board on a unit with no capacitive touch, no audio problem occurs.

According to the datasheet, the MODE pin should be set to 0 to select two-wire mode (basically I2C) and the CSB pin will control whether the slave address is 0x1A or 0x1B.  You should be able to do an i2cdetect to see if the device ACKS this address.  There's a description of the ACK at the bottom of page 46 of the datasheet.  If you don't get an ACK, you might have a hardware problem.

I think I found the problem: it seems due to the Capacitive Touchscreen always connected to I2C with its own right address (different from those of audio codec). When Touchscrren is correctly connected to I2C, no audio codec found. Removing Touchscreen connection, audio codec found ad sound is OK. I need to use both of them. Is there a solution?

Do you mean to say that when the touchscreen is connected, the codec won't even ACK its own I2C address?  If yes, there are a lot of possibilities.  Ensure both devices are operating at compatible voltage levels (e.g., 3.3V or 5V). Some I2C devices are not tolerant of different voltage levels, which can cause issues when both are connected.

Also, pull-up resistance is very important.  If the combined pull-up resistance on the I2C lines (SDA and SCL) is too high or too low, it could cause communication problems. For instance, too low a pull-up can result in high power consumption, while too high a resistance might not provide enough pull-up strength, particularly with multiple devices on the line.  If everything I mentioned is OK, you're best to start a new thread on electronics.stackexchange.com, because this goes into the hw domain.
